# Sort array in ascending order nested loop problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I am using a nested for-loop to rearrange array in ascending order.

The problem is with the ( y = x + 1 ) in the second(nested) for-loop. I get the following error: 
name lookup of 'x' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]

```
int i, y, temp;

    cout << "How many elements should be stored in array? ";
    cin >> i;

    int arr [i];

    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
        cout << "Enter value for element at index " << k << ": ";
        cin >> arr[k];
    }

    for( int x = 0; x < i; x++);
    {
        for (int y = x + 1; y < i; y++)
        {
            if (arr[y] < arr[x])
            {
                temp = arr[x];
                arr[x] = arr[y];
                arr[x] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

error: name lookup of 'x' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]

Comment: `int arr [i];` is not valid C++. And who is upvoting these sort of questions?

Comment: The fact that you assign twice in a row to `arr[x]` leads me to believe there is an error there. You probably meant to write `arr[y] = temp;`.

Comment: there is no other x defined in the code.

Comment: @NeilButterworth There is a difference between there being something wrong with the question and there being something wrong with the code. `int arr[i];` is a problem but with the code, not the question.

Comment: I see yes, but that unfortunately does not fix the problem

Comment: @François It's a bad question for any number of reasons  - primarily it won't compile and  it's asking us to debug it if it did compile. And if you are the person upvoting stuff like this (which is happening a lot lately), please don't.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I agree. Though your comment makes it seem like your objection to this question is the `int arr[i];`. Or did you mean that this is the reason it doesn't compile?

Comment: @François It's not C++, so that statement certainly is not compilable C++ code. Obviously, the entire code as posted cannot be compiled at all.

Comment: @DivanMeyer The compiler flag `-pedantic-errors` is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a semicolon after

`for( int x = 0; x < i; x++);`

Which needs to be removed to encompass the following block.

Answer (score 4):

Pay attention to the last `;`

```
for( int x = 0; x < i; x++);
```

and remove it.

If you don't then the next `{` starts a block where `x` is not defined, it died at that last `;`

Answer (score 2):

Issue is that you have

`int i, y, temp;`

and later

`for (int y = x + 1; y < i; y++)`

The later `y` hides previous one declared.
Hiding variable might be a source of bug.

Comment: Good catch. Oddly the warning complains about `x`.